# Why is my array variable undefined in my component when I try to use array methods on it?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm having an issue with displaying an array of Pokemon moves that I've retrieved from the database (using a rails/react/redux). The strange thing is that when I display the entire array without trying to use `join` on it, everything's fine. But when I try to use `join` on it, I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined`. And when I display the entire array variable as is, without modifying anything, it does display.

I've gone through my code and I've confirmed that the routing is fine and the right action creators are being dispatched. I've also gone through my reducers and I can confirm that they are using the right action constants to make decisions as to what the new state object is. The only thing that I can think of is that maybe the problem lies in one of these places below:

// the component that renders my Pokemon details onto the page

```
class PokemonDetail extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestSinglePokemon(this.props.match.params.pokemonId);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.pokemonId !== this.props.match.params.pokemonId) {
      this.props.requestSinglePokemon(this.props.match.params.pokemonId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { pokemon } = this.props;
    if (!pokemon) return null;
    return (
      <section className='pokemon-detail'>
        <figure>
          <img src={ pokemon.image_url } alt={ pokemon.name } />
        </figure>
        <ul>
          <li><h1>{ pokemon.name }</h1></li>
          <li>Type: { pokemon.poke_type }</li>
          <li>Attack: { pokemon.attack }</li>
          <li>Defense: { pokemon.defense }</li>
          <li>Moves: { pokemon.moves.join(', ') }</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

// the reducer

```
const pokemonReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  Object.freeze(state);
  let poke;
  switch(action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.pokemon);
    case RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON:
      poke = action.payload.pokemon;
      return Object.assign({}, state, { [poke.id]: poke });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

// the action creators

```
export const requestSinglePokemon = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(startLoadingSinglePokemon());
  return APIUtil.fetchSinglePokemon(id).then(pokemon => dispatch(receiveSinglePokemon(pokemon)));
}

export const receiveSinglePokemon = payload => ({
  type: RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON,
  payload
});
```

// the backend APIUtil method

```
export const fetchSinglePokemon = id => (
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `api/pokemon/${id}`
  })
);
```

It's the strangest thing...when I do `{ JSON.stringify(pokemon.moves) }` I can literally see that it is an array of strings (of Pokemon moves). And even when I just display it like this, `{ pokemon.moves }`, it seems to be correctly grabbing the right Pokemon; the name, type, attack, and defense text is all there and the moves is also displayed (although not correctly formatted).

NOTE: Upon observing my log (it shows me the action creators that are dispatched when I interact with the page), the error with `join` seems to pop up before (or instead?) of the action creator that should have been dispatched (i.e. I see that the `START_LOADING_SINGLE_POKEMON` action is never dispatched before this error pops up)

Answer (score 1):

for the first render of your app , no actions have been dispatched. 
componentDidMount occurs after initial render.
hence, unless the parent component of "PokemonDetail" is passing an intial pokemon object with key "moves " whose value is of type array, it would casue this error for first render.

you can either have conditional rendering inside "PokemonDetail" component based on "Pokemon" object or have inital state of "pokemon" contain moves array in reducers.

Comment: Ahh ok, so if I have a list of pokemon upon start of the app (for the user to choose from), then when I first load up the page, are the only actions that have been dispatched the ones to request and receive all pokemon? Or I guess a better question, when I first load up the app, even if I don't click on a pokemon from the initial list, is the "PokemonDetail" component still being loaded?

Comment: i can't say without looking at your ParentComponent of "PokemonDetail". 
even if it loads, now that i have seen your code clearly , if (!pokemon) return null, this should prevent the error. unless your reducer is not updating the state correctly.

Comment: Ok, yes, that's what I was thinking with the `if (!pokemon)` as well...I'll double check the reducer...I'll update the question with my reducer as well

Comment: reducer code looks correct. could you log the pokemon data in render method before return and check it ? or show here so that i can also check.

Comment: Yes! As an example, when I chose the the fifth pokemon from the list, this is what the `pokemon` is in the render method when I threw a debugger in there: `{id: 5, name: "Charmeleon", image_url: "/assets/pokemon_snaps/5-b47514f3eb8f165ebf18df794acd63f595d5177a32c9233f862741b2d1d95454.svg"}
id: 5
name: "Charmeleon"
image_url: "/assets/pokemon_snaps/5-b47514f3eb8f165ebf18df794acd63f595d5177a32c9233f862741b2d1d95454.svg"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Hmmm, so it looks like there are no `moves` in the pokemon object...

Comment: yep no moves in pokemon object. poke_type, attack , defence are rendered as undefined on screen i guess. but calling map on "undefined " is what causing the error.check backend code to receive correct response--APIUtil.fetchSinglePokemon

Comment: Hmm, so when I manually navigate to the url in my `APIUtil.fetchSinglePokemon`, the pokemon object has `moves` inside of it. However, when I access the `pokemon` object in the console after I click on the same pokemon from the list, it doesn't have the moves or any other of the keys that were in the object when I physically navigated to the url.

Comment: Am I perhaps doing something wrong in my action creator (in the promise) after I call `fetchSinglePokemon`?

Comment: in promise, you receved pokemon object as response, which is dipsatched as payload , may i know why your are doing poke = action.payload.pokemon; instead of poke = action.payload ?
also can you log insidepromise then method success handler to see pokemon object you are receiving contains moves propery ?

Comment: if still can't figure out , maybe the data you are passing from parent component of PokemonDetail must not be passing correct pokemon object as props ?

Comment: Hm, so if I do `pokemon.moves` and I throw a debugger into the `RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON` case in the reducer, I can see that `poke` does have `moves`. But when I try to do `pokemon.moves.join(', ')`, the error comes up first and it never hits the debugger. And the reason why I'm doing `action.payload.pokemon` is because a GET request to a specific pokemon returns an object with 2 nested hashes inside: the pokemon info and the pokemon's items.

Comment: I think I know what's happening, but I don't know where to look for the error. So initially my state only contains the pokemon's id, name, and image url. It's only after I click on a pokemon from the list when the state is updated with additional information about the pokemon (i.e. poke type, moves, etc.). But it seems that when I click on a pokemon from the list, it goes straight to the `render` method before dispatching the `requestSinglePokemon` action; hence the state is still in the initial state when it doesn't have the additional information...

Comment: then you have two options.

Comment: .1. initialize state like polemon={poke-type:"", attack:"",defense:"",moves:[]} or 2.<li>Type: { pokemon.poke_type || "" }</li> <li>Moves: { pokemon. moves?  pokemon.moves.join(', ') :"" }</li>

Comment: Ah I see, so when the app first loads, if I have a `<Route path='/pokemon/:pokemonId' component={ PokemonDetailContainer } />` in the Root component (which is rendered upon startup) is that component still rendered even though I'm not at that route?? Or is it skipped over?

Comment: I am also newbie to react. react documentation is good resource.  front end masters introduction to react by brian holt.if you want you can people on twitter,dan abramov, Ryan florence many react developers.

Comment: is that component still rendered even though I'm not at that route?? Or is it skipped ?? --- it wont be rendered. you can put console.log inside render method of the PokemonDetailContainer to verify.